# How do I create a multi-dimensional array in Javascript like shown in this picture?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are fixed three columns in it. The rows are added dynamically and may go up-to few thousands also.

I should also be able to iterate through the array and filter Id & Values based on level.

Is this possible ? How?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible.

Comment: You could build it from the ground up. But you could start with [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/index)

Comment: @hindmost, of course I have tried. I didn't write the code in my question because I don't want my code to influence other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays  of Arrays are easy.

```
[[1, 234,'Apple'],[2,23,'Sunday'], ....]
```

To add something to the array, push use `push`. To iterate `forEach`. `filter` is not yet in the JS standard, but here is a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

I suggest for your problem to look at not building an Array of Arrays, but model each row as a JS object:

```
{level: 1, id: 234, value: 'Apple'}
```

that way you can write more semantic code like

```
myObjectList.filter(function(obj){ return obj.level > 1 })
```

rather than using array indexes everywhere.

In general if you ant get an idea what you can do with JS built-ins like Array, check the JS reference at the Mozilla Developer Network. Its pretty good and has lots of examples for each Array function like `forEach` or `find`, or `filter`.